# Connecting Windows XP computer to Windows 7 computer

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-xp, connection, lan

Me and my friend are trying to connect 3 computers together: 2 using XP and one Windows 7. We have successfully connected the XP computer that is connected to the router directly with cable and the Windows 7 computer but the other Windows XP computer doesn't show in any workgroup that we've created. What might be the problem?

Comment: What versions of XP you're using? Both are XP professional?

Comment: Yes they are both WinXP Professional

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the workstation and browser services are started on the XP machine that is not appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the firewall on the 2<sup>nd</sup> XP machine is configured to let local network traffic through in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

- In XP's Firewall (`firewall.cpl`) enable the "File and Printer Sharing" exception;

  (if you use a third-party firewall, allow TCP 139, TCP 445, UDP 137, UDP 138 and ICMP Echo)
- Use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) to watch for browsing traffic (display filter `smb || nbss || nbns || netbios || browser`)
- In 7, try `nbtstat -a <HOSTNAME>` and `nbtstat -A <IPADDRESS>` (where `<HOSTNAME>` and `<IPADDRESS>` are the XP computer's name and IP address respectively); also check if they return the correct workgroup name.
- Try restaring the "Computer Browser" service in all computers

Comment: File and printer sharing is enabled 
nbtstat says that the host cannot be found (tried with IP adress also)
restarted the computer browser service and it didn't have effect